# Jquery keyup multiple inputs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make it so when someone uses the input the text that corresponds to it will show.

```
<div class="content1" style="display: block;">Content 1</div>
<div class="content2" style="display: none;">Content 2</div>
<div class="content3" style="display: none;">Content 3</div>
<div class="content4" style="display: none;">Content 4</div>

<ul class="addReview">
        <li><p>Input 1</p><input type="text" name="input1" value="" id="input1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  /></li>
        <li><p>Input 2</p><input type="text" name="input2" value="" id="input2" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  /></li>
        <li><p>Input 3</p><input type="text" name="input3" value="" id="input3" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  /></li>
        <li><p>Input 4</p><input type="text" name="input4" value="" id="input4" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  /></li>
    </ul>
```

Would I do a keyup function for each input or is there a way to make one keyup function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it for your current markup:

```
$('.addReview input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
   $('div[class^="content"]').hide();
   $('div.' + this.id.replace(/input/, "content")).show();
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WD3CU/

But it would be neater if you gave the divs a common class and different ids. E.g., if all the divs had a class "content" and an id in the form "content1" then you could do this:

```
$('.addReview input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
   $('div.content').hide();
   $('#' + this.id.replace(/input/, "content")).show();
});​
```

Which looks similar but is much more robust (the way I did it for your current html will likely break if you were to give the divs additional classes).

Demo incorporating my suggested markup changes: http://jsfiddle.net/WD3CU/1/

Also, in my opinion it would make more sense to use the `.focus()` event rather than `.keyup()`, so that the appropriate div is shown as soon as the user clicks or tabs into one of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind to a common selector like this

```
$('.addReview input:text').keyup(function() { });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5AV2J/1/)

Or a class selector like this

```
$('.addReview .mytextboxclass').keyup(function() { });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5AV2J/2/)

Or an attribute selector like in [nnnnnn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756234/295264)

```
$('.addReview input[type="text"]').keyup(function() { });​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WD3CU/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to modify your HTML architecture a bit. Change it to this:

```
<div class="content" id="content_1" style="display: none;">Content 1</div>
<div class="content" id="content_2" style="display: none;">Content 2</div>
<div class="content" id="content_3" style="display: none;">Content 3</div>
<div class="content" id="content_4" style="display: none;">Content 4</div>

<ul class="addReview">
    <li><p>Input 1</p><input type="text" class="input" name="input_1" value="" id="input_1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  /></li>
    <li><p>Input 2</p><input type="text" class="input" name="input_2" value="" id="input_2" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  /></li>
    <li><p>Input 3</p><input type="text" class="input" name="input_3" value="" id="input_3" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  /></li>
    <li><p>Input 4</p><input type="text" class="input" name="input_4" value="" id="input_4" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  /></li>
</ul>​
```

You can then use the following jQuery code to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
$(".input").keyup(function() {
    var curId = this.id.split("_")[1];
    $("#content_"+curId).html($(this).val());
    $("#content_"+curId).show();
});​
```

Working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kmkkn/).

Comment: Thanks for your help mate but thats not really what I was going for. The inputs value is unrelated to what I am trying to do. I want when someone clicks on the input to show a pre selected message to help them to answer the question. Kinda like when you ask a question on stackoverflow, how the right side gives you hints on your title and then body and then tags. Thanks for the help!